# flutter OpenContainer problems

Tags: flutter

Flexible(

```
          fit: FlexFit.tight, 
          child: OpenContainer(
            closedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
            transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            openBuilder: (context, _)  {
              return MealDetailScreen(
                meal: meal,
              );
            },
            closedBuilder: (context, openContainer) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: openContainer,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    meal.imagePath,
                    width: 150,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

The method 'OpenContainer' isn't defined for the type '_MealCard'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'OpenContainer'.

When i try use OpenContainer i am encountering this error. I dont have animations.dart in my flutter version.do i need this dart ? Or is there another source of the problem? What should I do to write the code in the correct format? Thanks to everyone who has helped/tryed to help so far!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `OpenContainer` is part of the [animations package](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) and if you want to use it, you must [install](https://pub.dev/packages/animations/install) it.